# Why does the following fragment of C program give this output?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
 {
  char c[] = "Gate2011";
  char *p = c;
  printf("%s", p+p[3]-p[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:** 2011

Why does it give this output? I tried different combinations and it always gives junk.

Comment: What do you think this code is doing?

Comment: It would help if I knew why the question was down-voted so I don't make that mistake again.

Comment: Why did you not load p, p[3] and p[1] into separate temp vars and printf them out ?

Comment: @nan the question was downvoted (not by me btw) because you haven't made any attempt to resolve this (rather simple) problem by yourself.

Comment: I did make an attempt. A lot actually. I even mentioned in the question that  I tried it with different combinations.

Comment: @nan OK, maybe you have made an attempt, but some explanations about it should be part of the question. "different combinations". What combinations ?

Comment: ^^exactly.  You just dumped what you had written, or, more likely, what was written in your homework assignment.  Also "2011" is not 'junk', it's plainly the last part of your string, starting with the 4th character.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Ok. Will keep that in mind.

Comment: @MartinJames I said when I tried other combinations in the printf statement it gave me junk. Not for this program.

Comment: I think this would make a good exam or interview question to test the understanding of pointers and `printf()`.

Comment: @iksemyonov That was exactly what I was preparing for :)

Comment: When I was watching SO of the past years, got the impression that it used to be a different place, and this wouldn't have been downvoted here. Times are changing.

Comment: Try to predict the output when you're not using ASCII... EBCDIC could surprize you in a bad way

Comment: @Elias, I expect the same results with ASCII and EBCDIC, because `101-97 == 133-129`.

Comment: @TobySpeight `a` and `e`... lucky break, imagine if the characters were `r` and `v`: 165 - 153 != 118 - 114...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because `p[3] = 'e' = 101` and
`p[1] = 'a' = 97`

101 - 97 = 4

`p + 4` = address of "2001" in "Gate2001"

interpreted as string ... there you go.

I also do not understand the downvotes :(

---

Comment: Ah! So it considers the ASCII value! I get it now. I thought p[3] would be the address of the third element.

Comment: @nan p[3] is the element with index 3 (NOT the third element, that is with index 2) in the string

Comment: @nan you need another specifier to output the address as int

Comment: Who the f is downvoting this decent analysis?!

Comment: @iksemyonov Those who forgot that one day they also were beginners :)

Comment: I would also add a note saying that the `%s` specifier outputs a null-terminated string, thus outputs "Gate2011" starting with position 4 to the end, for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Not necessarily ASCII - it depends on the character coding of your environment (see comments on the question).  But most (all?) codings in common use have `'e' == 'a' + 4`, so it's somewhat portable code.

Answer (score 0):

p+p[3]-p[1]
for p is the address of Ram address of string "Gate2011" ; for P[3] - p[1] will make actually a offset of visit to string ,that is 'e' - 'a' = 4
you can count where is it now.